# How to find the location index of a given Pandas dataframe index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In Python Pandas, how do you find the numerical index of a dataframe?

Consider the following example.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(20).reshape(5,4), index = np.arange(2,7),columns=["A","B","C","D"])

Output:

    A   B   C   D
2   0   1   2   3
3   4   5   6   7
4   8   9  10  11
5  12  13  14  15
6  16  17  18  19
```

How do you find the location index of the df.index == 4. The answer should be 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `get_indexer` notice the different here is `get_loc` will do one value per called , `get_indexer` you can pass a list

```
df.index.get_indexer([4])
array([2], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try `.get_loc`

```
In [4]: df.index.get_loc(4)
Out[4]: 2
```